# Microsoft SQL Server - Permission to create a Snapshot

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssis, snapshot

I've developed a set of SSIS packages to load a data warehouse. 
In order to manage any issue that may arise during package execution, each package starts by creating a snapshot of the data warehouse.

The package authenticates on my server using a login that does not belongs to the **dbcreator** server role.
Obviuosly with this configuration the package fails due to the lack of permission to create/drop a database.

The dbcreator server role allows a user to create/drop a database on the whole instance. 
My question is: Is there a way to grant a database user the permission to create a snapshot of the given database (and only that) and eventually drop the snapshot (and only the snapshot associated to the given database)?

What are the best practices to handle this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to do straight away as mentioned on [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Permissions Any user who can create a database can create a database
>   snapshot; however, to create a snapshot of a mirror database, you must
>   be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

What I understand is - if you could have alternative in place for DB creator role, this purpose can be achieved and this has been explained very well by one of MSSQL SME [Mr. Solomon Rutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/solomon-rutzky)

You can achieve this by using module signing which has been explained by Mr. Tibor Nagy on this link --> https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3336/how-to-use-module-signing-for-sql-server-security/

You can also refer the question and answer thread for better understanding of module signing at the same forum and how can this be used:

[Granting a user a permission to restore a database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260137/granting-a-user-a-permission-to-restore-a-database/260138#260138)

[Execute Permissions for a Store Procedure that creates databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238675/execute-permissions-for-a-store-procedure-that-creates-databases/238711#238711)

https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/02/15/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-server-level/

More about Module signing at Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms345102(v=sql.100)

Hope this leads you into right direction.